# ajax call with post parameter -not able to receive that parameters at server side

Tags: php, angularjs

I have added below call for ajax call

```
$http({
        url: "http://localhost/angular-js-apis/listing.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: {type: "list"},
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'}
    }).then(function mySuccess(response) {
        $scope.listing = response.data;
    }, function myError(response) {
        $scope.myWelcome = response.statusText;
    });
```

and at server site at below file code
http://localhost/angular-js-apis/listing.php

```
<?php

include("database.php");
echo "<pre>";var_dump($_POST);die("test to die");

?>
```

but in my server it prints only empty value of `$_POST`.

can anyone tell me what is an issue over here?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following snippet

**Angular**

```
$http.post(
    url: "http://localhost/angular-js-apis/listing.php",
    JSON.stringify({type: "list"})
).then(function (response) {
    $scope.listing = response.data;
}, function (response) {
    $scope.myWelcome = response.statusText;
});
```

**Server**

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
print_r($data);
```